# Deleting two tables with one query in sqlite android with common column and not referenced

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two tables Class and Students and I want, when Deleting table Class to delete those Students with the same Class id by using something like the following..

```
public Integer deleteClass (Integer id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("Class","_id = ? ",new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
}
```

with schema like the following

```
private static final String CREATE_STUDENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
    + STUDENTS_TABLE + "(" + TABLE_STUDENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
    + TABLE_STUDENT_NAME + " TEXT, "
    + TABLE_STUDENT_AGE + " TEXT, "
    + TABLE_STUDENT_CLASS_ID + " INTEGER, "
    + TABLE_STUDENT_AREA + " TEXT" + ")";

private static final String CREATE_CLASS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
    + CLASS_TABLE + "(" + TABLE_CLASS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
    + TABLE_CLASS_NAME + " TEXT, "
    + TABLE_CLASS_CAPACITY + " TEXT, "
    + TABLE_CLASS_POSITION + " TEXT"+ ")";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before deleting it from `Class`, delete all `Students` from same class.

```
public Integer deleteClass (Integer id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(STUDENTS_TABLE, TABLE_STUDENT_CLASS_ID + " = ? ",new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
    return db.delete(CLASS_TABLE, TABLE_CLASS_ID + " = ? ",new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
}
```

**Note : I am considering that table `Students` has column name `class_id` which is referenced from table `Class`.**

Comment: then how you know that some `student` belongs to which `class`?

Comment: so I reference the class_id like that.. public static final String CREATE_CLASS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + CLASS_TABLE + "(" + ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + NAME_COLUMN + " TEXT, " + CLASS _SIZE + " DOUBLE, "
            + CLASS _DEPARTMENT_ID + " INT, "
            + "FOREIGN KEY(" + CLASS _STUDENT_ID + ") REFERENCES "
            + STUDENT _TABLE + "(id) " + ")";

Comment: So I need to do it like above?

Comment: so you have to delete record using `TABLE_STUDENT_CLASS_ID` field. I edited the answer.. check it

Comment: yes it works without create a reference of foreign key